# Push notification with closed app . [Parse server]

Tags: java, android, push-notification, parse-server

I'm having trouble sending notifications when my app is closed, I read somewhere about services, but I'm a beginner on android and I do not quite understand. I've been able to make notifications work when the application is open, so here I am asking you for an orientation on how to get notifications with an app closed, any help will be appreciated if you have a code related to it and want to share it, help a lot! Thank you.

Comment: are you using firebase or just polling to your server from your app ?
Can you also add the android version used ?

Answer (score 0):

Services are background jobs that keeps running either your application is in running state or not. So, to show notifications while your application is not running you need to write a service for that your notification will be shown. Read the links below to know more

1. [Official Service Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)
2. [Android Service Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm)